# How to compute the p-value out of bootstrap

Tags: p-value, bootstrap

I am using the Current Population Survey (CPS) to compute a complex statistic that involves computing flows of people moving from employment to unemployment and then using those flows to compute the statistic I'm interested in.

I need to bootstrap to compute confidence intervals, which I know how to do. I create bootstrap samples of the original individual-level data, compute flows, and compute the statistic I am interested in. Out of these statistics, I look at the 2.5% and 97.5% percentiles. Great.

If I want to have the p-value of the statistic I am interested in being bigger than 0, can I just look at the percentile associated with the value 0? In other words, look at the mass of statistics that is above 0? I've read I need to shift the bootstrapped observations to have a distribution with a mean 0. If that is the case, I don't know how to do it given that my original sample contains individual-level data.

Thanks you!